# Creating a relation diagram from database with no constraints

Tags: sql, relational-database, diagram

Consider there is a huge SQL database that works fine but no constraints made during database conception. I need to make a relation diagram of database tables. Is there any tool I can use to do at least part of it for me?

Comment: No tool will be able to analyze it, but you can create a diagram by understanding the structure yourself.

Comment: To amplify @RobertMoskal quite correct statement:  there are tools that can output the table structures, but without actual constraints, you will have to join the diagram's tables yourself.